# Application/object error during paste special operation

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, runtime-error

I have been working in this code for a week now, I'm kind of new to VBA and am close to getting it to do what I need it to but I keep getting a "Aplication-defined or object-defined error" on the last line. My code is pretty simple, it asks for 3 imputs on Sheet1 positions them where they have to be than copies each information to the first line of Sheet2 in its appropriate cells, than it searches for the value of the first input or the value of the first cell called last4 (still working on that) add a row right above where the value is found on sheet2 and than copies the first row into that new empty row. now if I could just get rid of that error and properly search for the cell I want it should all run smoothly, any help appreciated.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Last4 As Variant
Dim SerialNum As Variant
Dim ExpDate As Variant
Dim addaul As Worksheet

Do

Last4 = InputBox("Insert the last 4 numbers on the NSN for the Hazmat", "RECEIVED HAZMAT")
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Last4
Sheets("AUL").Range("A1").Value = Last4

If Last4 = Blank Then Exit Sub

SerialNum = InputBox("Scan the Serial Number of the Hazmat", "RECEIVED HAZMAT")
Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = SerialNum
Sheets("AUL").Range("H1").Value = SerialNum

If SerialNum = Blank Then Exit Sub

ExpDate = InputBox("Insert the expiration date for the Hazmat", "RECEIVED HAZMAT")
Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = ExpDate
Sheets("AUL").Range("I1").Value = ExpDate

If ExpDate = Blank Then Exit Sub

Sheets("AUL").Select
Sheets("AUL").Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("AUL").Cells.Find(What:="Last4", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.EntireRow.Insert

Sheets("AUL").Range("A1:O1").Copy
Sheets("AUL").Range("A1:O1" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  <------ ERROR LINE IS THIS ONE

Loop Until Last4 = Blank
End Sub
```